# Find function return value in Matlab

Tags: matlab, find, return-value

The `find()` function in Matlab returns and empty 1x0 matrix if it is not able to find anything for the given criteria. How to check if this is indeed the case - that the given criteria is nowhere satisfied in the matrix provided?

Comment: @EitanT - Agreed - my mistake. I'll vote for closing.

Comment: You might find that logical indexing is more suited to your application than `find` is in which case you can test for the condition being met or not using the any function i.e. in Shai's example below you could write `if ~any(b == 4)` to get the same result but probably a bit faster.

Comment: That is quite helpful! thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check with `isempty`

```
b = [ 1 2 3 5 ]; 
a = find( b == 4 );
if isempty( a )
   fprintf(1,'not found\n');
end
```